# Realtek RTL8153 Ethernet Doesn't work on Arch Linux

Tags: usb, archlinux, ethernet, usb-hub, realtek

I'm trying to use one of these to boost my networking speed on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.
[image]

Arch Linux ARM correctly detects the USB hub, but fails to detect the Ethernet port. `ifconfig` does not show any new interfaces (It *should* show **eth1**).

**This adapter works on Raspbian!**

How can I get it working on Arch Linux?

**Kernel version**

```
Linux rpi2 3.18.14-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu May 28 07:19:33 MDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**Output from lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 067b:2773 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2773 SATAII bridge controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:2812  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Output from dmesg**

```
[  208.996060] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  209.002444] usb 1-1.3.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  216.399329] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[  216.513179] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812
[  216.521315] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  216.530324] usb 1-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[  216.536647] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[  216.552291] hub 1-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[  216.558958] hub 1-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  216.858855] usb 1-1.3.3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[  216.989200] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[  216.996777] usb 1-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  217.006738] usb 1-1.3.3: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[  217.012873] usb 1-1.3.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  217.017589] usb 1-1.3.3: SerialNumber: 00E04C680219
[  217.159217] usb 1-1.3.3: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[  217.340472] r8152 1-1.3.3:1.0 eth1: v1.07.0 (2014/10/09)
```

Comment: What does `ifconfig -a` or `ip link` show?

Comment: Ah. It does show `eth1`.  But why doesn't it show normally, like it does in Raspbian?

Answer (score 2):

From `man ifconfig`:

> **NOTE**
>
> This program is obsolete!  For replacement check ip addr and ip link.

Although that's not the problem here (it still works fine), I thought I'd point that out.  The issue is:

> If  no  arguments  are  given, ifconfig displays the status of the **currently active** interfaces [...] if  a  single -a argument is given, it displays the status of all interfaces, **even those that are down.**

Unless the system is configured to do otherwise, a newly attached interface is down.  To change that:

```
ip link set eth0 up
```

Or the obsoleted `ifconfig eth0 up`.

> why doesn't it show normally, like it does in Raspbian?

Again, that has to do with your network configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I know in the back of my mind that `ifconfig` is obsolete, but muscle memories die hard.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the solution is to make a new network config file in `/etc/systemd/network` containing:

```
[Match]
Name=eth1

[Network]
DHCP=both
```

This will make `netctl` go and fetch an IP.