# USB to ethernet dongle not working on A+

Tags: raspbian, ssh, ethernet, software-installation

I have an A+ I wanted to try use on my local network, so I installed Raspbian to an SD card, have a USB to ethernet dongle, and added a blank "ssh" file to the SD card root to be able to log in to it from my Mac.

When testing the USB dongle on my Mac (WiFi off, USB dongle to ethernet cable to my router) it works fine, but when I power up the A+ the leds on the USB dongle don't even light up, nor can I find any new MAC addresses or IP addresses in my router connection monitor nor via nmap. My assumption is that the A+ and the dongle don't play nice, but could there be something I can try aside from just assuming device incompatibility? Could it be because of the first time setup something goes amiss?

The A+ lights both red and green lights shortly when starting, then has the red one on. It's getting power from the mini USB with power converter from an outlet. Also I don't really have any spare screen I could use to run the A+ by itself, so the ssh option is the way to go I'm afraid. The USB dongle is of brand Anker.

Any ideas what to try?

Edit:
Here image of the USB ethernet dongle details as viewed when plugged into my Mac:
[image]

Comment: What "dongle" is it?  Do you know if Raspbian supports it?  Your RPi receives enough power?   Without screen, you could still go for a serial console to follow your RPi booting.  But I don't know if Mac has RS232, else you would need another "dongle", usb to RS232. BTW, what do you suppose to obtain with that "blank ssh file" ?

Comment: Several guides I read mentioned putting an empty ssh file in the root will allow you to ssh into the pi using a default user and password. [This is the USB dongle](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00NPJV4YY/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but I have very little clue how to determine if it is supported or not. I couldn't find the manufacturer in the supported list of Pi. I use a standard mobile charger's network part and use a USB mini cable from it to the PI; I'd imagine it gets all the power it needs, but what should I look for to be sure?

Comment: My RPi's are heavier and need a healthy 2A, but yours can do with a lot less - but you need to power the dongle too.  The dongle is USB 3.0, which made me worry, but they say its backwards compatible to USB 1.1. I doubt you'll get a Gigabit out of USB 1.  Please put the dongle in the Mac and find out the Vendor and Product ID's.  Also a link to one of the guides with the empty ssh file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please see the updated question with the USB info.

Comment: This adapter works on Raspbian! https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32262/realtek-rtl8153-ethernet-doesnt-work-on-arch-linux#32265  If I read correctly, the module is dwc_otg.  So something else is wrong.  Can you read the MicroSD in your Mac?   If so, you should try to read the logs, /var/log/dmesg, messages, ...

Comment: Okay; I followed the NOOBS install instructions: Format SD card, extract zip, copy to root, put into PI. There is no `/var/log` or anything looking like a "unixish" root I recognize.

Comment: I never used NOOBS (noblesse oblige) but normally there are at least two filesystems, no. 1 is the boot (VFAT), no. 2 is the root (ext4 ?).  The logs would be on the second partition.  This seems not to be the case for NOOBS though, all seems to be in a single FAT32 partition.

Comment: On the screenshot here, https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/backup/ I see there is a /var folder.  Didn't you find that one?

Comment: NOOBS instructions:  4. Copy the extracted files onto the SD card that you just formatted so that this file is at the root directory of the SD card. Please note that in some cases it may extract the files into a folder, if this is the case then please copy across the files from inside the folder rather than the folder itself.   Do you see the .DTB files in the root of the SD card?

Comment: Okay so I missed out on the fact that NOOBS installs an installer on the SD from which you select to install the Raspbian on first boot up - for which you obviously need peripherals. Trying with flashing the Raspbian image to the PI now and will see. Thanks for the help so far debugging this.

Comment: Hyvästi ja onnea!